# python super excute parent method

Tags: python, class, super

I have a question about python super().

here is my code

```
class A(object):
    def test(self):
        t = [self.__class__.__name__]
        return t

class B(A):
    def test(self):
        t = super(B, self).test()
        t.append(self.__class__.__name__)
        return t

B().test()
```

the result is [B, B]

but i want to get [A, B]

is possible to get [A, B] ?

thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`__mro__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__mro__#class.__mro__) attribute of the class.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def test(self):
...         return [c.__name__ for c in type(self).__mro__[-2::-1]]
...
>>> class B(A):
...     pass
...
>>> B().test()
['A', 'B']
>>> A().test()
['A']

>>> B.__mro__
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> B.__mro__[::-1]
(<type 'object'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>)
>>> B.__mro__[-2::-1]
(<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>)
```

Comment: Wow...nice answer. BTW, why can't I see the `__mro__` attribute by `print dir(B)`, but `print B.__mro__` does give the information you mentioned.

Comment: @WKPlus, [**Built-in Types - Special Attributes**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__mro__#class.__mro__) clearly states that: The implementation adds a few special read-only attributes to several object types, where they are relevant. Some of these are not reported by the `dir()` built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help you:

```
class A(object):
    def test(self):
        t = [A.__name__]
        return t

class B(A):
    def test(self):
        t = super(B, self).test()
        t.append(B.__name__)
        return t

B().test()
```

I think you want the name of class, not the instance class.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd add that contrary to apparent expectations, doing

```
 super(B, self).func()
```

where `A` is the superclass does NOT create a class of A, and then call the function. It simply finds the function in the namespace A, and calls it instead on the current class. Since the object hasn't changed, referencing `self.__class__` still points to the class `B`, and `self.__class__.__name__` is still the name `B`.

In fact, if you had something like

```
class A(object):
    def func(self, somearg):
        pass

class B(A):
    def anotherfunc(self, someotherarg):
        super(B, self).func(someotherarg)
        self.func(someotherarg)
```

the last two statements are actually identical... when you call a function, python will look through the MRO for the closest function in matches. Since B doesn't actually have a function called `func`, it will drop through to choose the one in A anyways.

Also, as the second answer, you can explicitly call `__name__` through the class method (through the class `A` or `B` directly) instead of through the instance... that will always reference the same class, no matter where it is called from.